# read until end of file after a matching string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to `readline` after a match as from a file:

```
with open(jij, "a") as jout:
  with open(jfile, "r") as jinp:
    for line in jinp:
      if line.strip().startswith("IQ"):
        # for _ in line:
        #for lines in jinp:
        for lines in range(2500):
          # lines = jinp.readline()
          rows = jinp.readline().split()
          print("{0:<3s}{1:<3s}{2:<3s}{3:<3s}{4:>3s}{5:>3s}{6:>3s}{7:>15s}{8:>7s}".
                format(rows[3], rows[2], rows[0], rows[1], rows[4], rows[5], rows[6], rows[11], rows[10]))
```

A very short `jfile` is(I generaly have around 1000 lines, but it may be even bigger):

```
                    Isotropic exchange couplings  Jij

  number of sites   NQ =   2
  number of types   NT =   2
  site occupation:
     1   1  1 1.000
     2   1  2 1.000
IQ   IT   JQ    JT   N1 N2 N3    DRX    DRY    DRZ     DR         J_ij [mRy]     J_ij [meV]
 1    1    2    2   -1 -1 -1  -0.500 -0.500 -0.681   0.982      0.159317355     2.167623834
 1    1    2    2    0 -1 -1   0.500 -0.500 -0.681   0.982      0.159317355     2.167623834
 1    1    2    2   -1  0 -1  -0.500  0.500 -0.681   0.982      0.159317355     2.167623834
 1    1    2    2    0  0 -1   0.500  0.500 -0.681   0.982      0.159317355     2.167623834
 1    1    2    2   -1 -1  0  -0.500 -0.500  0.681   0.982      0.159317355     2.167623834
 1    1    2    2    0 -1  0   0.500 -0.500  0.681   0.982      0.159317355     2.167623834
 1    1    2    2   -1  0  0  -0.500  0.500  0.681   0.982      0.159317355     2.167623834
 1    1    2    2    0  0  0   0.500  0.500  0.681   0.982      0.159317355     2.167623834
 1    1    1    1    0 -1  0   0.000 -1.000  0.000   1.000      1.457569899    19.831256008
 1    1    1    1   -1  0  0  -1.000  0.000  0.000   1.000      1.453728096    19.778985590
```

I am trying to print few elements as list after it finds "IQ".

My preferred way is to do it by `for _ in line` which is taking first 100 lines only; `for lines in jinp` is skipping one line, and reading the next line. It is only working as intended when I am putting it in range. But I don't want to put a fixed line number.

What is going wrong with `for _ in line`?

https://da.gd/CtKZ is the complete file.

https://da.gd/7V8F      result with `for lines in range(2500)`

https://da.gd/6cx3      result with `for _ in line`

https://da.gd/v9ts      result with `for lines in jinp`

Expected result is from `range(2500)`, but I dont want to hardcode the line numbers.

Comment: Could you post your output and the desired output ?

Comment: @t.m.adam: added

Comment: The `for _ in line` prints 100 lines because `len(line)` is 100 .  If you want to print the lines after "IQ" , you could put them in a list and iterate over that

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is u reuse the same fd:

```
  rows = jinp.readline().split()# This make the pointer point to next line
```

All your solutions have this line + another way iteration:

```
# for _ in line: go over the chars in the line (100)
#for lines in jinp: go over the open file - > so you read twice per iteration
```

You could use this, Shorter and more readable.

```
flag = False
with open(jij, "a") as jout:
    with open(jfile, "r") as jinp:
        for line in jinp:
            if flag:
                rows = line.split()
                jout.write("{0:<3s}{1:<3s}{2:<3s}{3:<3s}{4:>3s}{5:>3s}{6:>3s}{7:>15s}{8:>7s}\n".
                           format(rows[3], rows[2], rows[0], rows[1], rows[4], rows[5], rows[6], rows[11],
                                  rows[10]))
            else:
                flag = line.strip().startswith("IQ")
```